# sfGuardUser - session expired

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I add to table sfGuardUser new fields - is_online. If user login on my site then i set this field on TRUE. if he logout then i set FALSE, but how to set FALSE if lifetime session for these user expired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think is better to create a field on the sf_guard_user table where you set the last activity date.
everytime the user reload the page, you have to set this date with the current_timestamp.

now you can check with a date_diff the users login state!